# Vue - How to locate and read file on root folder, after build process

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I developed a web app that will be executed offline, from the SO file system. The client wants to add a file on the folder (along index.html) to be read by the web app. Is that possible?

I know that is possible to read files with javascript, but after the build process I don't know how to locate the file.

Comment: literary create "files" folder after build in root, and during build reference it.  /files/files... Or even not 100% sure if you crate manualy files folder in root of build will it be created after build in it. Also why not just make upload function? Did you even try anything?

Comment: I didn't thought about upload. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you use Vue. For example, if you are doing a **Vue CLI SPA project**, then any file that's in the `public` folder beside the `index.html` can be referenced as if it was in the root folder of the URL you use (e.g. `npm run serve` -> `http://localhost:8080` is the root; `http://localhost:8080/additionalfile.xyz` is accessible. It's another question what you can do with it, but it's accessible.)

More on the Vue CLI folder structure [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#html-and-static-assets)